# How to check which image is linked to ImageView in android?

Tags: android, imageview

Well i have one button and one ImageView in my app.
What i am trying to do is when i pressing on the button then the image at the ImageView will change.
All i have are two pics file.

What i am trying to do is - if the first pic is linked to the ImageView than change it to pic2 by clicking on the button, and if pic2 is linked than a click on the button will change it back to the first pic file.

here's the  onClick method i tried to use:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        ImageView ib1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)

         View p1 = findViewById(R.drawable.pic1); 

        if(ib1.getResources()==R.drawable.pic1){
            ib1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic2); 
        }else{
            ib1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1); 
        }

    }
```

Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: Why don't you keep the current value as a field in your activity? In Android isn't a good approach look in the view for data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rather than checking the image, I would suggest set the information tag of the `ImageView` each time you change the image, like:

```
if(ib1.getTag() != null && ib1.getTag().toString().equals("pic1")){
 ib1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic2); 
 ib1.setTag("pic2");
} else {
 ib1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1); 
 ib1.setTag("pic1");
}
```

Comment: Well first of all thank you for the quick and elegant solution, but can you help me understnd what is Tag stands for? where can i see it in the code. Because all i know that i can get to a view element by id or by it's location in the project folders - So Where this Tag sits, What does it means? and if there's a place where can i rename it statically in the code? - Once again thank you for your help

Comment: Tag is for storing temporary small data: developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 0):

```
private ImageView ib1;
private int currentImage;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ib1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    currentImage = R.drawable.pic1;
}

public void onClick(View view){
    currentImage = (currentImage == R.drawable.pic1) ? R.drawable.pic2 : R.drawable.pic1;
    ib1.setImageResource(currentImage);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a Boolean variable and assign it true and then if the boolean variable is true you change the picture of image button and set the boolean variable to false:- here my code example in java:-

```
package com.example.myapplication;

 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 android.view.View;
 import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton play_pause;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        play_pause = findViewById(R.id.play_pause_button);
        final boolean[] play_or_pause = new boolean[1];
        play_pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_arrow_24);
        play_or_pause[0] = true;
        play_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (play_or_pause[0]) {
                    
          play_pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_24);
                    play_or_pause[0] = false;
                }else {
                    
           play_pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_arrow_24);
                    play_or_pause[0] = true;
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

and xml code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="252dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TBT Music Player"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.087" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="247dp"
        android:layout_height="263dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_library_music_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.512"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.124" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="327dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:thumbTint="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.163"
        android:secondaryProgressTint="@color/white"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/play_pause_button"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="77dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_play_arrow_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.213" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```