# How to check which image is set on an image view in Android?

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am developing an application and it is having multiple image views and multiple images. I want to check, which image is set on an image view, and i want to put that same image in an another image view.
The application is having multiple images. How can i implement this programatically, specifically JAVA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check which current image resource is attached to ImageView in android xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23357706/how-to-check-which-current-image-resource-is-attached-to-imageview-in-android-xm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `tag` to `ImageView`,

Set a tag either in `xml` or dynamically
In xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageview" 
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_name"
    android:tag="drawable_name"/>
```

Dynamically,

```
ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
imageView.setTag("bg");
```

Use `imageView.getTag()` to retrieve image information.

```
String backgroundImageName = String.valueOf(imageView.getTag());
```

you can set tag when you change your drawable and get it by this method

You can see these question to get some other idea

[How to check which current image resource is attached to ImageView in android xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23357706/how-to-check-which-current-image-resource-is-attached-to-imageview-in-android-xm)

[How to check which image is linked to ImageView in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482272/how-to-check-which-image-is-linked-to-imageview-in-android)